# Why does Xcode think this is an optional?

Tags: swift, option-type

I am declaring a constant in this line of code but if I don't put the `! after it, xXcode gives an error saying:

> value of optional type string must be unwrapped.

Why does Xcode think this is an optional? I am just declaring a constant of type `String` and assigning it to a key that the user will set in the setting section.

Maybe because I am using the `UserDefault` settings and it's not set yet? If so, how do I get around that?

```
let jbEmail: String = userDefaults.string(forKey: "JBemail_preference")!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the documentation for `UserDefaults string(forKey:)`. It has a return type of `String?`. It returns an optional because there might not be a value for the given key.

So your attempt to assign a `String?` to a `String` results in the error. The forced unwrap (adding `!`) resolves the error but it is the worst possible solution because now your app will crash if there is no value for the key.

You should properly handle the situation where there is no value for the key in `UserDefaults`.

You can assign a default value:

```
let jbEmail = userDefaults.string(forKey: "JBemail_preference") ?? "Some Default"
```

Or you can conditional deal with there being no value:

```
if let jbEmail = userDefaults.string(forKey: "JBemail_preference") {
    // Do something with jbEmail
} else {
    // There is no value, do something else
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what i was thinking... too

Comment: I actually also thought of using a gurad staement.  It seems to work...  Do you thing Guard or what you proposed is better?

Comment: ugh sorry for many comments keephitting return by mistake.  I tried this .  guard let jbEmail = userDefaults.string(forKey: "JBemail_preference") else{
     createAlert(title: "Settings", message: "You must go to Settings - AREQ and enter your email adress EXACTLY as it is set up on device. Capital and small letters count. For help/suggestions email: kencfii@aol.com")
        return
    } . seems to work

Comment: `guard` is fine. There are many ways to properly handle optionals. I just gave a few as an example.